# Add change-request to the list of acceptable tags on Meta

Tags: feature-request

Not every proposed change is a new feature.  I suggest that on meta, we also allow the tag change-request as one of the required tags when someone proposes a change to an already existing feature.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in the two is insignificant enough in context of posting something here on meta that I don't think there's a need for both tags.

Comment: +1, though I'd go further: I don't even think there is a difference at all.

Answer (score 3):

If the tag was "new-feature" I would agree, but the current tag is "feature-request". That could be assumed to mean either a new feature or a change to a current feature.